# Twitter's "effective scala" broker example and tail recursion

Tags: scala, memory, recursion, stack-overflow

In the document "[Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/#Twitter%27s%20standard%20libraries-Offer/Broker)" published by twitter, I see a code example:

```
class Pool(conns: Seq[Conn]) {
  private[this] val waiters = new Broker[Conn]
  private[this] val returnConn = new Broker[Conn]

  val get: Offer[Conn] = waiters.recv
  def put(c: Conn) { returnConn ! c }

  private[this] def loop(connq: Queue[Conn]) {
    Offer.choose(
      if (connq.isEmpty) Offer.never else {
        val (head, rest) = connq.dequeue
        waiters.send(head) { _ => loop(rest) }
      },
      returnConn.recv { c => loop(connq enqueue c) }
    ).sync()
  }

  loop(Queue.empty ++ conns)
}
```

The code doesn't appear to be tail recursive, and isn't annotated as such.  Since this is a connection pool that would presumably be left running for the life of the program, what would prevent a pool like this from eventually blowing up the stack, and generating a StackOverflowException?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is not recursive at all! `loop` does not call itself. It passes closures `{ _ => loop(rest) }` and `{ c => loop(connq enqueue c) }` to `waiters.send` and `returnConn.recv` respectively which call `loop` again. No recursion hence no stack overflow.

Comment: `send` and `recv` don't take thunks per se, but the apply method on the `Offer` they return do take transformers (in this case `(Conn)=>Unit`) which are effectively callbacks on successful transactions (`Tx.Commit[Conn]`), so each call of `loop` retains a closure over only the immediately-previous call's `connq`.